# Finding next greater element

Tags: python, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is the [Daily Temperatures](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/description/) problem at leetcode.com:

> Given a list of daily temperatures, produce a list that, for each day
>   in the input, tells you how many days you would have to wait until a
>   warmer temperature. If there is no future day for which this is
>   possible, put 0 instead.
>
> For example, given the list temperatures = [73, 74, 75, 71, 69, 72,
>   76, 73], your output should be [1, 1, 4, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0].
>
> Note: The length of temperatures will be in the range [1, 30000]. Each
>   temperature will be an integer in the range [30, 100].

This code works for smaller inputs and fails for list of length 10,000. What would you recommend me to change or improve in this code?

```
class Solution(object):
    def dailyTemperatures(self, temperatures):
        """
        :type temperatures: List[int]
        :rtype: List[int]
        """
        #O(n2)
        #max(temperatures)
        res=[]
        for i in range(len(temperatures)):
            cnt=0
            for j in range(i+1,len(temperatures)):
                cnt+=1
                if temperatures[i]<temperatures[j]:
                    res.append(cnt)
                    cnt=0
                    break
                elif j==len(temperatures)-1:
                    res.append(0)
                    cnt=0
                    break
        res.append(0)           
        return res
```

Comment: How does it fail for large lists? Does it just exceed the time-limit of the online-judge? If so, please add the tag [tag:time-limit-exceeded]. If it crashes somehow, then your code is broken and not yet ready to be reviewed. We can only look at working code here. Have a look at our [help/dont-ask] for more information.

Comment: why don't you check the [solution](https://leetcode.com/problems/daily-temperatures/solution/) on the site where the problem was posed?

Comment: I want to know how I can modify my approach to make it better, thats the reason why I posted it here.

Answer (score 4):

Start by setting your `res` list with \$ 0 \$ values. Thus:

```
res = [0] * len(temperatures)
```

You won't need the `elif` condition now. Nor would you need the ending `res.append`. All `res.append` inside the loop will be replaced by `res[i] = counter` values.

Use a more descriptive variable naming than skipped vowels (`counter` instead of `cnt`, `result` instead of `res` etc.)

You compute `len(temperatures)` a total of \$ n^2 \$ number of times. Keep the value inside another variable instead.

As for the complexity, your current algorithm is \$ O(n^2) \$, which might be reduced by using a more efficient algorithm. Take a look [at this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19722651/1190388) making use of a LIFO queue (stack) and getting the results in \$ O(n) \$.

Answer (score 1):

Make res a list of zeroes. Also, make an empty list called cache. This will store the indexes of temperatures in the temperature list.

```
res = [0] * len(temperatures)
cache = []
```

Process the temperatures in reverse.

```
for i in reversed(range(len(temperatures))):
```

Remove the cached values that are smaller than or equal to the temperature you are processing. Make sure you check if the list is empty. These are not needed as you have a temperature that is closer to the temperatures that you will to process (remember we are processing the temperatures in reverse) and is warmer.

```
while cache and temperatures[i] >= temperatures[cache[-1]]:
    cache.pop()
```

Since this loop could have been stopped because the list is empty, check if the list has values in it. Then add the difference between the last cached value and the index of the current temperature you are processing to `res`. If cache is empty we know there aren't any future temperatures higher than the current one, so we don't need to change it as it is already 0.

```
if cache:
    res[i] = cache[-1] - i
```

Then for each temperature cache the index of the temperature you just processed.

```
cache.append(i)
```